# How to delete Facebook comment on a web page completely

Tags: facebook, spam-prevention

I have static content in which I have used Facebook comments. A user had posted spam links in one of the pages. I logged in as a moderator and deleted said comments and, banned the user and marked it as spam. Despite this action Facebook displayed the message: "Comments from USERNAME will only be visible to his friends. Undo". As the message says it gave an undo link.

The problem is in future when search bots crawl Facebook comments and if they use the links posted in the comment which leads to spam websites then I may get a penalty for linking to spam sites.

So how do I remove the comments entirely from facebook? So that not even the users friends should see it.

Answer (score 2):

I am very sorry to say that what you are looking for is currently not possible. That's just how facebook is designed.

Having said that I would personally advise you to not worry about such a petty matter.